# How to correctly write <img src> in php without escaping to HTML

Tags: php, image, joomla, src

I am having trouble with my PHP code.  I've been changing everything for 6 hours and I still get Parse errors no matter what I do.  This is the code:

```
$slider3 = '<img src="'templates/' . $this->template . '/images/slider/slider3.jpg'">' . '" alt="' . $sitename . '" />';
```

The only way I can figure to not get it to throw an error is by writing it this way:

```
$slider3 =  '<img src="templates/" . $this->template . "/images/slider/slider3.jpg" .  "/>"';
```

but I don't think that's right.

I want $slider3 = "templates/MYTEMPLATE/images/slider/slider3.jpg" then later I will echo $slider3;

I get so confused with all the single and double quotation marks.  I think the first one is right - I look at it and study it and it looks right to me.  But it throws a parse error.

Comment: As a general rule of thumb '' is considered an Array of Characters, where as "" is considered a String, though a string is an array of characters, this isn't such a big deal in php (other programming languages it is). So in PHP a string can contain ', and an array of characters can contain " if you want to use " in a string you can always escape it by writing something like $var = "\""; // output => ".

Comment: please accept an answer if your question has been answered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$slider3 = '<img src="templates/'.$this->template.'/images/slider/slider3.jpg"/>';
```

should work.

Explanation:

```
'<img src="templates/'
```

is a single-quoted string, which happens to contain a double-quote (which is needed for the html src attribute, or any other html attribute value really)

```
.
```

(dot) is the string concatenation operator. It concatenates ("glues") the first string together with...

```
$this->template
```

which is presumably a string containing the name of the template (not clear from your code example). Note that if $this->template comes from user input, or an otherwise unvalidated source, it could be used for cross-site scripting, eg. if it contains "><script>alert("XSS!")<script>, javascript is executed in the browser!

```
.
```

another concatenation with...

'/images/slider/slider3.jpg"/>'

which is another single-quoted string which happens to contain a double-quote, ending the src attribute value.

Comment: Thank you so very much.  That helped me a lot.  Really.  I am using it in Joomla, so $this->template just gets the folder name of the template from Joomla.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$slider3 =  '<img src="templates/"' . $this->template . '"/images/slider/slider3.jpg"/>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$template = "MYTEMPLATE";
$slider3 =  '<img src="templates/'.$template.'/images/slider/slider3.jpg"/>';
echo $slider3;
```

Will echo - >

```
<img src="templates/MYTEMPLATE/images/slider/slider3.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just write:

```
<?php
$templates = "var";
echo  "<img src='templates/${templates}/images/slider/slider3.jpg'/>";
```

it will result in

```
<img src='templates/var/images/slider/slider3.jpg'/>
```